# Proof $\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{x_j \in A_j} x_j=\sum_{x_j \in A_j, \cdots, x_n \in A_n } \prod_{j=1}^{n}x_j$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have $n$ countable sets of real numbers $\{A_j\}_{j=0}^{n}$, I know that for each $A_j$ $\sum_{x_j \in A_j} x_j$ converges absolutely, so $\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{x_j \in A_j} x_j$ does exist.

How can I prove that: 
$$\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{x_j \in A_j} x_j=\sum_{x_j \in A_j, \cdots, x_n \in A_n } \prod_{j=1}^{n}x_j$$

Answer (score 0):

We will first consider a lemma: If $\{ a_{i} \}, \{ b_{j} \}$ are two sequences such that $\sum a_{i} = A$ and $\sum b_{i} = B$ and they are absolutely convergent then $\sum_{i,j}a_{i}b_{j} = AB$. (This elementary proposition).

Assuming the lemma we use induction on $n$. 
So we have $$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(\sum_{A_{j}} x_{j})= (\prod_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{A_{j}} x_{j})\times(\sum_{A_{n+1}} x_{j}) = (\sum_{A_{1} \ldots A_{n}} \prod x_{j})\times (\sum_{A_{n+1}} y_{j}) =  \sum_{A_{1}, \ldots A_{n+1}} \prod_{i=1}^{n+1}x_{i}.$$

The last step follows from the lemma from the fact that at each step $\sum_{A_{1} \ldots A_{n}} \prod x_{j}$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Does $\sum_{i,j}a_{i}b_{j}$ converges absolutely (!)? It seems that you use in the proof the fact that convergence of $\sum_{i,j}a_{i}b_{j}$ is absolute.

Comment: I am trying to prove the elementary proposition: $AB=(\sum_i a_{i})(\sum_j b_{j})=(\sum_i)(\sum_j a_{i}b_{j})$ to go ahead and say that it is equal $\sum_{i,j}a_{i}b_{j}$ I would need to show that $a_{i}b_{j}$ converges absolutely, so the order of summation does not matter, but can I prove the lemma without this assumption?

Comment: If $\sum_{i} a_{i}$ and $\sum_{j} b_{j}$ converge absolutely then so does $\sum_{i}a_{i}^{2}$ and $\sum b_{j}^{2}$. Now for $\sum a_{i}b_{j}$ you can bound their partial sums by that of $\sum_{i}a_{i}^{2}$ and $\sum b_{j}^{2}$ using Cauchy Schwarz.

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz I am aware of says that $|\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}b_{i}|   \le (\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}^2)(\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i}^2)$, But how can you use it to bound $\sum a_{i}b_{j}$?

Comment: Use CS for $\{ |a_{i}| \}$ , $\{ |b_{j}| \}$. It will give you the required bound.

Comment: do we both realize that we are talking about "cross product" of two series $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$? So even with absolute values CS gives $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_{i}b_{i}|   \le (\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}^2)(\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i}^2)$ which is a boundary but not for the "cross product" of the series but rather for the "inner product". I am not sure that "cross product" and "inner product" terms applies to series but I am trying to make the point that $\sum a_{i}b_{j}$ is not the same as $\sum a_{i}b_{i}$.

Comment: So you want to show that the partial $\sum |a_{i}b_{j}|$ converges. Using Cauchy criterion it suffices to show given $\epsilon > 0$  there are integers $m,n$ such that for any $p > 0$  $| \sum_{(m+i _{k}, n+j_{k}), k=0} ^{p} a_{m+i_{k}} b_{n+j_{k}}| < \epsilon $. But to show this we can use Cauchy Schwarz on the finite length $p+1$ vectors $(a_{m+i_{k}})$ and $(b_{n+j_{k}})$.